# Documenting multiple POST request for OAUTH under same resource RAML

Tags: oauth, raml

I realize that the title might be a little bit confusing so here is what I am trying to achieve:

I need to document token_grant and token_refresh methods using RAML both of which are POST calls.

**token_grant**: generate the first time OAuth token 
**token_refresh**: refresh the access token

They differ in query parameters and of course different return results. The problem is they are both under the same resource and RAML allows only 1 POST call for each resource:

```
 /oauth/token
```

Is there a way I can work around this, being limited to one post call?
Maybe having something conditional to be depending on the query parameters?

Here is the template for **token_grant**

```
/oauth/token:  
   post:
     description:
     headers:
       Authorization:
         type: "string"
         default: "[client_id:]"
         required: true
         example: 
     queryParameters:
       grant_type:
         type: string
         required: true
         example: ''
       code:
         type: string
         required: true
         example: ''
     responses:
       200:
         body:
         application/json:
       example: |
```

And here is the template for **token_refresh**:

```
/oauth/token:  
   post:
     description:
     headers:
       Authorization:
         type: "string"
         default: "[client_id:]"
         required: true
         example: 
     queryParameters:
       grant_type:
         type: string
         required: true
         example: ''
       //Main difference1
       refresh_token:
         type: string
         required: true
         example: ''
     responses:
       200:
         body:
          application/json:
          //Main difference 2
          example: "a different response goes here"
```

So the main question would be how to put these together under

```
/oauth/token/
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be compliant with the OAUTH2 spec, you should use `formParameters` instead of `queryParameters` because these values are passed in an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST body. This won't change your issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify the OAuth2 protocol in RAML, as this security scheme is supported by default: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#security

All you need to define are URIs, grants and scopes: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#oauth-20 and the header in which you expect the access token: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#declaration-1

Any OAuth2 aware client will have then enough information to use your API because the OAuth2 spec itself describes the code/token resource interactions.

Comment: I was asking something a little bit different. Since RAML experts are rarely found, let me expand my question with comments rather than opening a new one. 1)What if I wanted to actually document Token_Grant and Token_Refresh methods instead of having them as a schemes for rest of the API. Or say I want to be manually "Try It" the 2 methods and get a refresh token or an access token. Would that be possible?

Comment: 2) Going back to your point. Picking it up from the Dropbox example in the RAML documentation you have linked, you are saying that I only need -oauth1 part of the scheme? Since when I try to specify both -oauth_2_0 and -oauth_1_0 it throws the error "mapping are not allowed here" at the type declaration of OAuth 1.0

Comment: 1) Yes, but as I said, you'll need to use optional query params for the params that vary between grant and refresh. Plus the user will have to know what field to fill and what to skip in "Try it".

Comment: Oh so basically what you are saying is setting the differing parameter's required:false and putting an explanation in the description. Ok that makes sense!

Comment: 2) Weird, this deserves a new question so your RAML file can be inspected.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will accept your answer for this and link the new question here if you would want to take a look. Thank you again